# can't find haml partials in rails 2.3.8 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partials

The haml partials work fine in development, but are not found in production.  I know 2.3.8 is pretty old, but I need to stay with it for a while.

UPDATE: I found that if I remove the following line or set it to false in the production.rb environment file, the problem goes away.

`config.action_view.cache_template_loading            = true`

I haven't figured out what is going wrong but it seems to have to do with template cashing.  Any ideas?

Comment: try restarting the server in production. if the haml gem was recently added to the Gemfile, you need to restart the server in order for the server to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using WebBrick so I am restarting the server every time to switch between development and production.  (I know it is slow and not preferred for production.)  I have been using the haml gem for a long time.  I have just been running in development and now I want to run production.